# Chart is not defined, chart.js in javascript template

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having some trouble getting charts to show up. I get the error "chart is not defined" although it seems to be defined when I hover over it in my javascript template. Here's my code:

javascript file

```
var myChart = new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["Lag 1", "Lag 2"],
    data: [10, 5],
    backgroundColor: ["red", "green"]
  },
  options: {}
});
```

html file

```
<div>
<link href="{% static 'main/formwrapper.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
  <div class="desktop1-formwrapper">
    <div class="desktop1-frame2">
        <canvas id="myChart" style="width: 60%"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="desktop1-frame1"></div>
    <button class="desktop1-buttondefault">
      <span class="desktop1-text3">Nästa runda</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

the base html file which I extend, and where I have my links to javascript template and chart.js

```
    <script src="{% static 'main/dropDownToggle.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
         src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.2/chart.min.js">
    </script>
```

I'm probably missing something simple, but I can't figure it out, thankful for some advice!

Update. Entire base.html where I link javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %}

<html lang="english">
  <head>
    <title>Med Andra Ord</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <style data-tag="reset-style-sheet">
      html {  line-height: 1.15;}body {  margin: 0;}* {  box-sizing: border-box;  border-width: 0;  border-style: solid;}p,li,ul,pre,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {  margin: 0;  padding: 0;}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea {  font-family: inherit;  font-size: 100%;  line-height: 1.15;  margin: 0;}button,select {  text-transform: none;}button,[type="button"],[type="reset"],[type="submit"] {  -webkit-appearance: button;}button::-moz-focus-inner,[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {  border-style: none;  padding: 0;}button:-moz-focus,[type="button"]:-moz-focus,[type="reset"]:-moz-focus,[type="submit"]:-moz-focus {  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;}a {  color: inherit;  text-decoration: inherit;}input {  padding: 2px 4px;}img {  display: block;}html { scroll-behavior: smooth  }
    </style>
    <style data-tag="default-style-sheet">
      html {
        font-family: Inter;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      body {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style:normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        line-height: 1.15;
        color: var(--dl-color-gray-black);
        background-color: var(--dl-color-gray-white);

      }
    </style>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
      data-tag="font"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kalam:wght@300;400;700&display=swap"
      data-tag="font"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
      data-tag="font"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/style.css' %}" />
    <script src="{% static 'main/dropDownToggle.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
         src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.2/chart.min.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <link href="{% static 'main/desktop1.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />

      <div class="desktop1-container">
        <div class="desktop1-desktop1">
          <span class="desktop1-text">
            <span class="desktop1-text01">MED ANDRA</span>
            <span class="desktop1-text02">ORD</span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %}

<html lang="english">
  <head>
    <title>Med Andra Ord</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <style data-tag="reset-style-sheet">
      html {  line-height: 1.15;}body {  margin: 0;}* {  box-sizing: border-box;  border-width: 0;  border-style: solid;}p,li,ul,pre,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {  margin: 0;  padding: 0;}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea {  font-family: inherit;  font-size: 100%;  line-height: 1.15;  margin: 0;}button,select {  text-transform: none;}button,[type="button"],[type="reset"],[type="submit"] {  -webkit-appearance: button;}button::-moz-focus-inner,[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {  border-style: none;  padding: 0;}button:-moz-focus,[type="button"]:-moz-focus,[type="reset"]:-moz-focus,[type="submit"]:-moz-focus {  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;}a {  color: inherit;  text-decoration: inherit;}input {  padding: 2px 4px;}img {  display: block;}html { scroll-behavior: smooth  }
    </style>
    <style data-tag="default-style-sheet">
      html {
        font-family: Inter;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      body {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style:normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        line-height: 1.15;
        color: var(--dl-color-gray-black);
        background-color: var(--dl-color-gray-white);

      }
    </style>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
      data-tag="font"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kalam:wght@300;400;700&display=swap"
      data-tag="font"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
      data-tag="font"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/style.css' %}" />
    <script src="{% static 'main/dropDownToggle.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
         src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.2/chart.min.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <link href="{% static 'main/desktop1.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />

      <div class="desktop1-container">
        <div class="desktop1-desktop1">
          <span class="desktop1-text">
            <span class="desktop1-text01">MED ANDRA</span>
            <span class="desktop1-text02">ORD</span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <link href="{% static 'main/formwrapper.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
        <div class="desktop1-formwrapper">
          <div class="desktop1-frame2">
              <canvas id="myChart" style="width: 60%"></canvas>
          </div>
          <div class="desktop1-frame1"></div>
          <button class="desktop1-buttondefault">
            <span class="desktop1-text3">Nästa runda</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}

  <script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels: ["Lag 1", "Lag 2"],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [10, 5],
          backgroundColor: [
            "red", "green"
          ],
        }]
      },
      options: {}
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: These changes aren't related to the error, I still get "Uncaught reference error. Chart is not defined"...

Comment: seems like the ChartJs library is not being imported. Could you post the whole html file? Maybe you import the library too late? Try moving the library import into the head part of the html.

Comment: Added the entire base.html. I also tried using a different function from my javascript template (same place where my chart function is) and that worked fine...

Comment: it does not seem to have the initial canvas, does not it?

Comment: I have the canvas in the html file i posted first

Comment: ok, I will edit my answer to contain a working solution

Comment: Yea it worked having the script anywhere but inside my javascript template, thought I tried that earlier but I guess I did something wrong. Still weird not being able to put it inside my js template. Anyway, this works fine, thank you very much for the help!